# Menú desplegable JQuery Tabledit: ¿Se puede traer valores de base de datos MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Estoy usando la libreria jquerytabledit,lo que quiero hacer es que al presionar editar unos de mis campos me traiga los datos de mi base de datos en forma de combobox.

Este es el archivo de mi boton editar donde defino tres opciones de modelo pero de forma manual

```
$('#tabla').Tabledit({
url: 'example.php',
eventType: 'dblclick',
editButton: false,
columns: {
   identifier: [0, 'id_marca'],
editable: [[1, 'des_marca'],[2, 'des_modelo','{"1":"A44440-A4000"}',"2":"AC0-FDA-S50D4A"}',"3":"DSA5D1A-8DASD451"}']]
}
```

});

*Lo que quiero es traer los datos mi base de datos en forma de combobox*

Answer (score 0):

Lo que creo que deberías hacer es hacer una consulta a la base de datos y sacar el texto y luego ponerlo en el input como placeholder o texto editadle. como un input con un default text de entrada

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).